# How to embed social media posts in Flutter Web project?

Tags: html, flutter, flutter-html

I'm looking to present and embed social media posts (from different platforms such as Twitter, Facebook, etc) on my **Flutter Website**.

I tried several packages such as `flutter_webview` or `social_embed_webview`, but I struggled to make them work on the Web.

I'm looking for working examples.
Thanks.